# Data not being bound to a selection in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am having an issue with binding data where the data is being bound to certain selections but not others.

For context, I have a series of rows in a csv file. Using d3, I iterate over each row and generate an svg for each row in the csv file. As demonstrated below.

```
var svgArea = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("class", "barSvg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

I then intend to use this selection to bind a `<g>` element and series of `<rect>` elements to the svg selection:

```
//creating a <g> elements
var vehicleText = svgArea.select("g")
.data(d)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("id", function(d) {return "vehicle_" + d.vehicle});

//creating a grouped bar chart
var vehicleBars = svgArea.selectAll("rect")
.data(d.sales)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("class", "vehicleBars")
.attr("id", function (d) {return "vehicle_" + d.vehicle + "_" + d.year})
.attr("width", width / 4)
.attr( "x", function (d){
  return xYears(d.year)
})
.attr("y", function(d){
  return yScale(d.value)
})
.attr("height", function(d) {return height - yScale(d.value)})
.attr("fill", function(d) {return colorScale(d.year)});
```

The issue is that the `<g>` element doesn't appear however the `<rect>` elements do despite using the exact same selection. I have been thinking that this is might be an issue with the way I am binding data to the elements. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Why does it bind the data for the one set of elements but not the set which proceeds it? [For reference, here is my code](https://plnkr.co/edit/L6MWf8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems here:

1. There are already `<g>` elements in the svg. So, instead of `select("g")`, your enter selection should select something that doesn't exist, like `selectAll("foo")`.
2. `d` is an object. However, the `data` function only accepts three things: an array, a function or nothing. So, it should be `data([d])`.

This problem #2 explains why, as you said...

> the data is being bound to certain selections but not others.

... and why your `console.log(vehicleText.datum())` returns `Cannot read property '__data__' of null`

That being said, here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/igliOTB1eq1k31eQ9nY5?p=preview

This, however, is not the best way to achieve what you want, nor the way I'd do it myself: have in mind that here I'm only answering your question, and nothing more.

PS: don't use `d` as the parameter for the data in your `chartGenerator` function. In D3 codes, `d` is usually used for the first parameter (the datum) in anonymous functions. Using `d` as you did will add some confusion, specially for seasoned D3 coders.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer.

Comment: After scrutinizing the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data), I can see that `d` in accepts only functions, arrays or none as you said.  

For future reference, could you provide some input on why my method is not best way to achieve want I want?

Comment: What I meant by *it's not the best way* is that I'd bind the data to the groups, and then I'd create the bars and the texts inside each group based on that data. Besides that, despite some people create small multiples using several SVGs, I like the approach of using only 1 SVG and several groups inside it, one for each sub-chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the properties to the label texts.  Try this way.

```
  var vehicleText = svgArea.append("g")
    .attr("id", "vehicle_" + d.vehicle); 

  vehicleText.append("text")
    .attr("class", "annotation")
    .attr("dx","4em")
    .attr("dy",height+20)
    .text( d.vehicle);
```

```js
var rows = [{
    "vehicle": "Ford F - Series PU",
    "Mar-2016": 65179,
    "Mar-2017": 72089,
    "perc_change": 10.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Chevrolet Silverado PU",
    "Mar-2016": 45009,
    "Mar-2017": 45280,
    "perc_change": 0.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Dodge Ram PU",
    "Mar-2016": 34152,
    "Mar-2017": 36885,
    "perc_change": 8
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Toyota Camry",
    "Mar-2016": 30942,
    "Mar-2017": 28189,
    "perc_change": -8.9
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Toyota RAV4",
    "Mar-2016": 27376,
    "Mar-2017": 28116,
    "perc_change": 2.7
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Honda Accord",
    "Mar-2016": 25571,
    "Mar-2017": 27182,
    "perc_change": 6.3
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Toyota Corolla / Matrix",
    "Mar-2016": 24183,
    "Mar-2017": 26747,
    "perc_change": 10.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Nissan Rogue",
    "Mar-2016": 22566,
    "Mar-2017": 26629,
    "perc_change": 18
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Honda CR-V",
    "Mar-2016": 25939,
    "Mar-2017": 25758,
    "perc_change": -0.7
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Honda Civic",
    "Mar-2016": 25052,
    "Mar-2017": 25303,
    "perc_change": 1
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Ford Escape",
    "Mar-2016": 20806,
    "Mar-2017": 23012,
    "perc_change": 10.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Chevrolet Equinox",
    "Mar-2016": 19636,
    "Mar-2017": 21600,
    "perc_change": 10
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Toyota Highlander",
    "Mar-2016": 12742,
    "Mar-2017": 21241,
    "perc_change": 66.7
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Nissan Altima",
    "Mar-2016": 20573,
    "Mar-2017": 20039,
    "perc_change": -2.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Ford Explorer",
    "Mar-2016": 16690,
    "Mar-2017": 19628,
    "perc_change": 17.6
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "GMC Sierra PU",
    "Mar-2016": 16520,
    "Mar-2017": 18900,
    "perc_change": 14.4
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Chevrolet Malibu",
    "Mar-2016": 10813,
    "Mar-2017": 18577,
    "perc_change": 71.8
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Subaru Outback",
    "Mar-2016": 13075,
    "Mar-2017": 17769,
    "perc_change": 35.9
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Ford Fusion",
    "Mar-2016": 19446,
    "Mar-2017": 17560,
    "perc_change": -9.7
  },
  {
    "vehicle": "Jeep Grand Cherokee",
    "Mar-2016": 17653,
    "Mar-2017": 17230,
    "perc_change": -2.4
  }
];


// Code goes here

//setting the margins
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 20
}

//setting width and height
var width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

yearVals = ["Mar-2016", "Mar-2017"]

//ranges
var xVehicles = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width], .1).paddingInner(0.1);

var xYears = d3.scaleBand().domain(yearVals).range([0, xVehicles.bandwidth()])
  .paddingInner(.1)
  .paddingOuter(5.0);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 85000]).range([height, 0]);

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#87ceeb", "#00bfff"]);


rows.forEach(function(data) {

  chartGenerator(data)
})

d3.selectAll("svg.barSvg")
  .data(rows)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.vehicle;
  })



function chartGenerator(d) {

  d.sales = yearVals.map(function(year) {
    return {
      "vehicle": d.vehicle,
      year: year,
      value: +d[year]
    }
  })

  //create vehicle name
  var vehicle = []
  vehicle["name"] = d.vehicle;


  var svgArea = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "barSvg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .append("g");

  //vehicleText not appended to g element


  //console.log(vehicleText.datum());

  var vehicleBars = svgArea.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d.sales)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "vehicleBars")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return "vehicle_" + d.vehicle + "_" + d.year
    })
    .attr("width", width / 4)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xYears(d.year)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.value)
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - yScale(d.value)
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.year)
    });

  var vehicleText = svgArea.append("g")
    .attr("id", "vehicle_" + d.vehicle);

  vehicleText.append("text")
    .attr("class", "annotation")
    .attr("dx", width / 4)
    .attr("dy", height + 20)
    .text(d.vehicle);

}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  width: 1200px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.barSvg {
  background: white;
}

.vehicleData {
  background: grey;
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
}

.annotation {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h2>Auto Sales - March 2017</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, You anticipated my follow up question regarding svg text elements.

Comment: Do you want to style the texts? You can customize texts just like any other SVG elements (By setting its attributes or styles). https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element